# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_type() on null in Custom plugin functions on the same page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a custom plugin based on https://wppb.me/

In my class-tshirt-public.php I have the following function.

```
public function list_categories() {

$args = array ('post_type' => 'tshirt-themes','orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );      
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <select>
    <?php
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <ul>
        <option value="<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>"> <?php echo get_the_title(); ?> </option>
    </ul>
        <?php 
    endwhile; ?>    
     </select> 
     <?php
    endif;
}
```

and in the same file I have a function that registers it as a shortcode.

In the thsirt-public-display.php file I have the following.

```
 <h1>Loaded Categories</h1>
  <?php $this->list_categories(); ?>
 </div>
```

When I load the page I get the following error, which gives me no information on the problem.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_type() on null in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php:1170 Stack trace: #0 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart('') #1 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #2 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-includes/plugin.php(453): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #3 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php(61): do_action('woocommerce_sin...') #4 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-includes/template.php(690): require('/Applications/M...') #5 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-core-functions.php(180): load_template('/Applications/M...', false) #6 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php(37): wc_get_template_part('content', 'single-product') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/tshirt/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php on line 1170
```

I can only assume that its conflicting with the woocommerce templates but I do not know the best practices when making these queries.

Answer (score 0):

if you use action hook : 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', you should use get_posts($args) instead of 'WP_Query'

```
public function list_categories() {
    $args = array ('post_type' => 'tshirt-themes','orderby' => 'name','order' => 'ASC' );
    $loops = get_posts( $args );      
    if ( $loops ) : ?>
       <select>
       <?php
       foreach ($loops as $key => $value) {?>         
        <option value="<?=$value->ID ?>"> <?=$value->post_title?> </option>   
       <?php 
       } ?>    
       </select> 
     <?php
    endif;
}
```